# custom view type in view format?

Tags: list-view

SharePoint provides the ability to create a new view for any list by choosing a view type. For example, SP allows me to create a view of type calendar by specifying which columns defines the start date, end dates, label in the calendar view.

Is there any way to create a custom view type, that is not related to a specific list, but that I can reuse with any list by mapping the view properties and the list columns ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe not.  Those are hard-coded in the TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\viewtype.aspx file.  The only thing you can do it attach a view to a list.  By creating a new view:

```
list.Views.Add("VIEWNAME", ALL THE FIELDS YOU WANT TO DISPLAY, Query, COUNT, true, false);
list.Update();

SPView view = list.Views["VIEWNAME"];
```

Now you can update the view properties